# Git ignores autocrlf config flag

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

I'm trying to contribute to a git project whose source files have CRLF line endings. When cloning the project, git immediately marks all the source files as modified. My config is:

```
$ git config --list
push.default=simple
user.email=xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxx
user.name=xxxx
merge.defaulttoupstream=true
merge.tool=kdiff3
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.autocrlf=false
remote.origin.url=xxxx.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

As shown above, autocrlf is set to false, which *should* tell git to ignore line endings.

The project has a `.gitattributes` file, which looks like this:

```
# Sources
*.c   text eol=crlf
*.cc  text eol=crlf
*.cxx text eol=crlf
*.cpp text eol=crlf
*.CPP text eol=crlf
*.c++ text eol=crlf
*.hpp text eol=crlf
*.HPP text eol=crlf
*.h   text eol=crlf
*.H   text eol=crlf
*.h++ text eol=crlf
*.hh  text eol=crlf

# Project files
*.sln     text eol=crlf
*.sdf     binary
*.opensdf binary
*.suo     binary
*.vcxproj         text eol=crlf
*.vcxproj.filters text eol=crlf
*.vcxproj.user    text eol=crlf

# Compiled Object files
*.slo binary
*.lo binary
*.o binary
*.obj binary

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch binary
*.pch binary

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so binary
*.dylib binary
*.dll binary

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai binary
*.la binary
*.a binary
*.lib binary

# Executables
*.exe binary
*.out binary
*.app binary
```

After cloning the project, the files do have CRLF line endings as they should:

```
$ file src/charbuf.cpp 
src/charbuf.cpp: C source, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Any ideas why git still marks them as modified?

Comment: No answers? Do you need more information?

Comment: Does a `git diff` show that the line endings have changed? Do you have a `smudge`  filter acting on files when they are checked out?

Comment: `git diff` shows differences for all files, but the typical `^M` characters are missing from the output, so both versions look the same. What is a smudge filter?

Comment: Smudge Filters are described here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes (Search for `These are called “clean” and “smudge” filters`)

Comment: Also, what is the output of `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i autocr`? (This should show all the autocrlf settings and the configuration files which are the source of each of these entries)